# delete multiple relationships in codeigniter datamapper orm

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

I have two models:
users and groups
user has many groups
and group has many users

I try to delete all groups of a user like this, which is not working

```
$user = new User(1);
$user->groups->delete_all();
```

Is there a solution to delete all multiple relationships for a model ?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to delete data from multiple table and you have a relation like foreign key you can use this following function by just passing table names (array) and your field name..

```
function deleteMultiple($tables = array(),$condition = array())
{
    if($condition)
        $this->db->where($condition);
    $this->db->delete($tables);
    return;
}
```